# How hide Keyboard in Redux?

Tags: android, reactjs, redux, react-redux, keyboard

I have a react redux web.
This web is to use it on an android device with self-keyboard, I don't want the screen keyboard, and I need to hide or block the android default keyboard.

I have seen that in react native you can hide the keyboard, but I can't apply this with redux.

Can anyone help me hiding android keyboard in redux?

Thnks

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do at all with Redux - Redux only manages your state, it does not change how you use React or React Native in any way.